react material-UI dataTable csv encode
I have a dataTable in react material-UI which has some Persian text in header and table cells, When I try to export the CSV, Persian texts are encoded abnormally like this: Ú©Ù„Ù…Ù‡ Ú©Ù„ÛŒØ¯ÛŒCSV export of table with Persian text
I tried setting the encoding format to utf-8 but it seems not working:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';

const exportCSV = (columns, data) => {
    const csv = [columns.join(','), ...data.map(row => row.join(','))].join('\n');
    const encodedCSV = iconv.encode(csv, 'utf-8');
    const blob = new Blob([encodedCSV], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    const name = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedProject'))['url'].replace(/https?:\/\/|\/$/g, '');
    saveAs(blob, `${name}_serp_range.csv`);
};

export default function SerpRangeTable() {
    const options = {
        filter: false,
        fixedHeader: true,
        fixedSelectColumn: true,
        customToolbar: () => <CustomToolbar onDateChange={handleDateChange} selectedDateRange={selectedDateRange} />,
        onDownload: (buildHead, buildBody, columns, data) => {
            const csvData = data.map(d => d.data);
            exportCSV(columns.map(col => col.label), csvData);
            return false;
        },
        textLabels: {
            toolbar: {
                search: "جستجو",
                downloadCsv: "دانلود CSV",
                print: "خروجی PDF",
                viewColumns: "نمایش ستون ها",
            },
        },
    };
return (
        <div dir="ltr">
            {loading ? (
                <MUIDataTable
                    title={"جدول بازه ای رتبه ها"}
                    data={Array.from({ length: 8 }, () => [<Skeleton variant="text" animation="wave" />, '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])}
                    columns={columns}
                    options={options}
                />
            ) : (
                <MUIDataTable
                    title={"جدول بازه ای رتبه ها"}
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                    options={options}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}


It looks like the text is UTF-8 encoded, but MS Excel doesn't handle it properly. I often see my native Cyrillic texts in a similar view, so I suppose it is UTF-8.

For me MS Excel shows Cyrillic properly when I don't open CSV file, but when I create a new empty table and then import data from CSV specifying the encoding (UTF-8) and the delimiter (comma).
